# Why Spring Facet is not detected and it is not listed under Framework dropdown list?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea

Brieflly, i have a problem with **Intellij IDEA Community Edition** precisely the **version 2019.3.15**.

My problem is that i imported a Spring boot application already generated using **Spring Tool Suite(STS)**. The importation has been done correctly without any warnings and problems, but i noticed that the project has **no Facets detected**, i tried to fix that by going to **Project settings** => **Facets** => **+**  and i found out that Spring Facets is not listed in the dropdown list please look at the image bellow :

[image]

Has anyone faced the same problem ? is it an IntelliJ bug? And if you have any suggestions please comment it bellow ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring support is [available only in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate edition](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html).